# What are state space equations?

Tags: passive-networks, network

I'm in a Linear Circuits semester II class, and we're going over 2 port networks. State space equations show up on the practice exams but not the lecture slides or book.

I was wondering if they were another name for the z, y, h, g, T or t parameters, and if not, how to find them. I'm not sure if they're going to be on this exam but I'd rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: The link offered below should prove a start.  State Space approaches are often taught as control systems exercises, and control systems courses are a bit out of vogue right now for reasons beyond my understanding.  I do remember (vaguely) learning how to raise e to a matrix power (or was that a nightmare?)/

Comment: @ScottSeidman That was real. Thanks for bringing those memories back...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frequency-domain transfer functions are one way of representing the behavior of linear time-invariant systems.  'State space' is another.

In the state space representation, the system is represented as collection of coupled linear first-order differential equations.  There are four matrices (usually called A, B, C, and D) that define these differential equations and show how system inputs affect the internal state, how outputs are derived from the internal state, and how the internal state evolves with time.

I recently gave a [short intro talk](https://github.com/tobin/statespace-intro-talk) on 'state space'.  Maybe the slides will be handy for you.

[image: State Space representation]

Answer (score 3):

See if this will give you a start.  [WikiBooks/Control Systems/State-Space Equations](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/State-Space_Equations)